# scipy.fft.fft output behaviour vs T/f_signal ratio

Tags: python, scipy, fft

I am observing a behaviour I cannot explain, when exploring the output of `scipy.fft.fft`

First a description of what I'm doing, then the code and result.

I am setting an observation window of 10 seconds, divide it in N = 1600 instants, therefore sampling a sinusoid of variable frequency, with a sampling time T_s = 10/1600 = 6.25ms.

I then calculate the FFT through the function provided by `scipy.fft` module. I normalize the result to the number of samples `N` as it is customary, to get the amplitude of the sinusoids back.

However, I find that the max amplitude of the output of the FFT is depending on the frequency of the sinusoid I am feeding into `scipy.fft.fft`. According to my understanding, this should not be the case as the sinusoids I am transforming are all of equal amplitude.

I found this effect is going with a sinc(\pi*t/T) function, so I can correct if I want to, however I don't understand **why** this is happening. Please note:

I don't think this is spectral leakage, as this would appear as energy around the fundamental and not as a progressive scaling. Moreover, the frequencies I'm choosing for the sinusoids are such that all signals fit an integer number of periods within the observation window, so I am not expecting any truncation effects.

Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.fft import fft, ifft
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'qt')

N = 1600 # FFT n. of points
T = 10 # observation window
Ts = T/N # sampling time
print('Sampling time: {}ms, Nyquist freq: {} Hz'.format(Ts*1e3,1/(2*Ts)))
t = np.linspace(0.0,T,N) # time vector, N points over (0,T)

plt.figure()
for f in np.linspace(5,80,16,dtype=int)[:-1]:
    y = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t)
    yf = fft(y)
    plt.plot(np.abs(yf)/N)
```

This is what comes out:

[image: Raw output of FFT]

As one can note, only the frequencies close to DC have the correct 0.5 amplitude (because one has to sum up positive and negative frequencies to get the full amplitude, this is OK).
Going up with frequencies, but still within Nyquist limit (80Hz in the example) and for frequencies integer multiple of f_s = 1/T = 0.1 Hz, there appears to be a scaling factor I can't account for, from theory.

**Note** this is reported in the `scipy.fft` [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/fft.html) example too, but it does not seem to bother them, so I assume this is a known effect?

There, the following signal:

```
y = np.sin(50.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x) + 0.5*np.sin(80.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x)
```

Is reported to have the following spectrum:

[image]

Whose bin amplitudes appear to be inconsistent with the signal in time domain (which has amplitude 1 and 0.5 for the two sinusoids composing it, whereas the FFT returns 0.7 for the first one, and 0.5 for the second one).

I found empirically that the 'scaling function' is a sinc(\pi*t/T), as if the original time domain signal was *convolved* with a pulse function. However, this does not make sense from a theoretical point of view, since the time domain signal is **multiplied** with a time window, not convolved, and this is at the origin of the spectral leakage phenomenon. As said, however, in this case this effect should not be visible because the signals are all repeating an integer number of times within the observation window (T)

A corrected plot using the following code:

```
win_seed = np.append([1],np.sin(np.pi*t[1:int(N/2)]/T)/(np.pi*t[1:int(N/2)]/T))
win_correct = np.append(win_seed,win_seed[-1::-1])

plt.figure()

for f in np.linspace(5,80,16,dtype=int)[:-1]:
    y = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t)
    yf = fft(y)
    plt.plot(np.abs(yf)/N/win_correct)
```

Gives a constant amplitude for the `scipy.fft`:

[image]

Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the following line:

```
t = np.linspace(0,T,N)
```

By default, `np.linspace` includes the endpoint so you get a sampling rate that is just slightly off from your desired `1/T` sampling interval. Correspondingly the sampling point in the spectrum obtained with the `fft` in the frequency-domain are just slightly off the actual peaks, with an offset that gets more noticeable as the frequency of the sinusoids gets closer to the Nyquist rate.

To get the desired `1/T` sampling interval with `np.linspace`, you should drop the endpoint by changing the line to:

```
t = np.linspace(0,T,N,endpoint=False)
```

With the following spectrum (without sync compensation):

[image]

Note that in the above graph you do not see the spectral leakage effect that should be expected. This is because the default number of points for the FFT makes it such that the spectrum is sampled at exactly at the zero-crossings of the peaks' skirts. I suspect that may be the reason why [`scipy.fft`'s documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/fft.html) you've seen (which tries to explains the spectral leakage effect) purposely chose frequencies that are slightly off. However, another way to see this leakage would be to simply increase the number of FFT points by some small factor (e.g. 4):

```
yf = fft(y,4*len(y))
```

With the following resulting spectrum (showing the expected peak magnitude *and* the spectral leakage effect):

[image]